# How to read the entire urls from the first column in a csv file

Tags: python, url

I am trying to read the urls from the first column in a csv file. In the csv file, there are 6051 urls in total which I want to read. To do so, I tried the following codes:

```
    urls = []
    with open("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/urls.csv") as csvfile:
        blogurl = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in blogurl:
            row = row[0]
            print(row)
```

### len(row)

However, the number of urls that are shown is only 65. I have no idea why the total number of urls appears differently from the csv file.

Can anybody help me with figuring out how to read all urls (6051 in total) from the csv file?

To read all the urls from the csv file, I also tried several different codes that resulted in the same number of urls (i.e., 65 urls) or failure, such as:
1)

```
    openfile = open("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/urls.csv")
    r = csv.reader(openfile)
    for i in r:
        #the urls are in the first column ... 0 refers to the first column
        blogurls = i[0]
        print (blogurls)
    len(blogurls)
```

2)

```
    urls = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/urls.csv")
    with closing(requests.get(urls, stream = True)) as r:
        reader = csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), delimiter = ',', quotechar = '""')
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            len(row)
```

3)

```
    with open("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/urls.csv") as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if i == 0:
        for line in csvfile:
            print(line[1:])
            len(line)
```

4) and

```
    blogurls = []
    with open("C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/urls.csv") as csvfile:
        r = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for i in r:
            blogurl = i[0]
            r = requests.get(blogurl)
            blogurls.append(blogurl)

    for url in blogurls:
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    len(blogurls)
```

I expect the output of 6051 urls as originally collected in the csv file, instead of 65 urls.

After reading all the urls, I am going to scrawl down the textual data from each url. I supposed to get the following textual data using all 6051 urls. Please click the following link for the image:

[the codes and the outcomes based on 65 urls so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZWMx.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible that you post part of the CSV file here? Might be a formatting issue (unexpected newline characters or separators).

Since your CSV is not very large, you could read it in in full `with open(...) as csvfile: content = file.read()`. Then you could do some analysis to check if the file is read correctly, e.g. see if `len(content.splitlines()) == 6051`.

Comment: @EliasStrehle Thank you for your suggestion. I tried your code and it shows the total number of 6051. However, the links are still only 65. In addition, using the codes you suggested, I cannot extract the textual data that I was able to (please see the attached image in my question). Would you mind me sending me the csv file to your email or other channels? I was unable to find how to attach the file here. Thank you again!

Comment: Try to separate getting the list of URLs from actually crawling them. That makes it easier to debug.

What do you see when you run the loop with `print(row)`? Does it print only 65 URLs or does it print 6051 URLs?

Comment: When I run print(row), it shows the 65 urls although there are actually 6051 urls in the first column. I am not sure why the codes can't read all 6051 urls. I need all the urls to scrawl down the textual data from them (shown in the image above). Would you mind trying again with my csv file?

Comment: Can you upload somewhere public? On GitHub for example?

Comment: @EliasStrehle I have uploaded the csv file on GitHub at: https://github.com/GemmyMoon/MultipleUrls.git. Please let me know if you are unable to see the file or access the link. Thank you for your check!

Answer (score 1):

The following two approaches work for me:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GemmyMoon/MultipleUrls/master/urls.csv')
urls = r.text.splitlines()

print(len(urls))  # Returns 6051
```

and

```
import csv
import requests
from io import StringIO

r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GemmyMoon/MultipleUrls/master/urls.csv')
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(r.text))
urls = [line[0] for line in reader]

print(len(urls))  # Returns 6051
```

Comment: Wow, I will try these. Thank you for your check!